# How do I make it so that the PHP if statements in wordpress don't have line breaks?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to make it so these awkward line breaks don't appear in spots where information isn't present on the sidebar here (see Official Links):
http://www.kaerumusic.com/music-album/lucky-number/

I'm using if statements and adding the content via shortcode:

```
<?php
$officialweb = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-official-website-url' );
$officialblog = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-k-m-official-blog-url');
$wikia = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-wikia-url'); 
$wikipedia = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-wikipedia-url'); 
$officialyoutube = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-official-youtube-url'); 
$officialnnd = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-official-niconicodouga-url'); 
$officialtwitter = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-official-twitter-url'); 
$officialfacebook = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-official-facebook-url'); 
$ann = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-anime-news-network-url');
$mal = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wpcf-km-myanime-list');
?>
<?php if ( $officialweb ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-official-website-url" title="Official Website"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $officialblog ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="k-m-official-blog-url" title="Official Blog"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $wikia ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-wikia-url" title="Wikia"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $wikipedia ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-wikipedia-url" title="Wikipedia"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $officialyoutube ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-official-youtube-url" title="Official Youtube"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $officialnnd ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-official-niconicodouga-url" title="Official NicoNicoDouga"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $officialtwitter ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-official-twitter-url" title="Official Twitter"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $officialfacebook ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-official-facebook-url" title="Official Facebook"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $ann ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-anime-news-network-url" title="AnimeNewsNetwork Page"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $mal ) :?><?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="km-myanime-list" title="BMyAnime List Page"][/types]'); echo '<br />'; ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to make it so those spaces don't show up when there isn't anything entered?

Comment: What is the value of, for example, `$officialblog`? `var_dump($officialblog);`

Comment: What does `get_the_terms()` return? It looks like your if statements might be returning true, but your `do_shortcode()` just isn't returning anything.

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary `<?php ?>` statements. It could be made a lot more legible by taking all but the first and last <?php statements out and assigning your results to a variable (e.g. `if(...) { $shortcodes.=do_shortcode(...); }`. Your last statement could be `echo $shortcodes."\n";?>`

Comment: Erg, the var_dump returned:
`object(WP_Error)#758 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }`
Weird, because it's a custom field and not a taxonomy.
I'm using the Types plugin, should I just go to the community forums for it and check for answers there? ( @showdev )

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your if statements. I don't see the "$officialblog" link, but it seems `if ( $officialblog )` results to `true`, thus outputting unwanted `<br/>`. Like @showdev said, take a look at the `$officialblog` value and build proper if statements so that it will actually result to `false`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the variables are empty or not. Like this:

```
if ( $officialweb && !empty( $officialweb ) && !is_wp_error( $officialweb ))
```